# input type range, noUiSlider не делает десятичные числа

Tags: javascript, input

Нужно сверстать вот такой input range, использую noUiSlider.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получилось сделать обычную шкалу от 1 до 10, например, а вот такие десятичные значения, да еще и с неравным интервалом никак не получается.. В документации ничего похожего не нашла. Очень нужно сделать, может кто что посоветует? Другой плагин?

Пробовала вручную стилизовать, тоже как-то не очень. В хроме еще отображается шкала, в мозилле нет.

Вот код для обычной шкалы

```
noUiSlider.create(range, {
        tooltips: true,
        connect: [true, false],
        range: {
            'min': 1,
            'max': 10
        },
        start: [1],
        step: 1,
        pips: {
            mode: 'count',
            values: 10
        },
        format: {
            to: function (value) {
                return parseInt(value);
            },
            from: function (value) {
                return parseInt(value);
            }
        }
    });
```

Для десятичной пробовала вот так, но не сработало:

```
noUiSlider.create(driver, {
    tooltips: true,
    connect: [true, false],
    // step: 10,
    range: 
        {
        'min': 2.45,
        '7%': 2.3,
        '14%': 1.55,
        '21%': 1.4,
        '28%': 1.0,
        '34%': 0.95,
        '42%': 0.9,
        '49%': 0.85,
        '56%': 0.8,
        '63%': 0.75,
        '70%': 0.7,
        '77%': 0.65,
        '84%': 0.6,
        '91%': 0.55,
        'max': 0.5
    },
    format: {
      to: function (value) {
          return parseInt(value);
      },
      from: function (value) {
          return parseInt(value);
      }
    },
    start: 0,
    pips: {
        mode: 'positions',
        values: [0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 34, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 77, 84, 91, 100]
    }        
});
```

Comment: есть [какой-то ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557385/how-to-set-up-a-decimal-range-0-5-1-step-0-05-with-nouislider). и он похож на решение данной проблемы

Comment: не совсем подходит, потому что там десятичные дроби идут через равномерный промежуток - 0,1. А у меня всяко-разно прыгают.. Комментарий ниже очень помог)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать вот такой вариант.

```js
var valuesRange = [
  2.45,
  2.3,
  1.55,
  1.4,
  1.0,
  0.95,
  0.9,
  0.85,
  0.8,
  0.75,
  0.7,
  0.65,
  0.6,
  0.55,
  0.5
];
var snapSlider = document.getElementById('slider-snap');
noUiSlider.create(snapSlider, {
  start: [3],
  connect: true,
  step: 1,
  pips: {
    mode: 'steps',
    filter: () => 1,
    density: 5,
    format: {
      to: (val) => {
        return valuesRange[val];
      }
    }
  },
  range: {
    'min': 0,
    'max': valuesRange.length - 1
  }
});

var snapValues = [
  document.getElementById('slider-snap-value-lower')
];

snapSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  snapValues[handle].innerHTML = valuesRange[+values[handle]];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/14.0.2/nouislider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/14.0.2/nouislider.css" />
<div id="slider-snap"></div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="slider-snap-value-lower"></div>
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо большое!