# Как сделать multiple slider, с нестандартным диапозоном?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

задался таким вопросом, как возможно сделать слайдер с несколькими ползунками с нестандартным диапазоном? Чтобы от 2-х до 100, но при этом все это выглядело так.

[image: Ползунок с нестандартным диапазоном]

Что-то ничего на ум не приходит, есть какие доводы?

Comment: Один серый блок `width: 300px; height: 3px; position: relative;`, внутри него два филалетовых `border-radius: 50%; position: absolute;`... легче будет сперва писать всё для клика, разобраться с получением координат при клике ( `event.pageX - clicked.offsetLeft` и т.п. ). А уже потом расширить до mousedown - mousemove - mouseup. Будет нужен внешний объект который всегда будет хранить и обновлять координаты кругов - чтобы как-то обрабатывать случай, когда будут пытаться перетащить одно поверх другого)

Comment: Посмотрите данный вопрос. У вас принцип похожий https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1047846/input-type-range-nouislider-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0/1047874?noredirect=1#comment1790352_1047874